# java android-studio double fraction only shows .0

Tags: java, double

Problem in my calculation system is that the output fraction of double always shows 0
like 77.3 in my calculation results but in program output it shows 77.0

here's the code of my program

```
public void  avgcal()
{
    double avg = .0,tot,wg1,wg2,wg3,wg4,dq1,dq2,dq3,dq4,st1,st2,st3,st4,intot1,intot2,intot3,intot4;

    DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat(".2");

    //Subject grades calculator
    wg1 = Double.parseDouble(ed2.getText().toString());
    dq1 = Double.parseDouble(ed3.getText().toString());
    st1 = Double.parseDouble(ed4.getText().toString());

    wg2 = Double.parseDouble(ed8.getText().toString());
    dq2 = Double.parseDouble(ed9.getText().toString());
    st2 = Double.parseDouble(ed10.getText().toString());

    wg3 = Double.parseDouble(ed11.getText().toString());
    dq3 = Double.parseDouble(ed12.getText().toString());
    st3 = Double.parseDouble(ed13.getText().toString());

    wg4 = Double.parseDouble(ed19.getText().toString());
    dq4 = Double.parseDouble(ed20.getText().toString());
    st4 = Double.parseDouble(ed21.getText().toString());

    intot1 = st1 / dq1 * wg1;
    intot2 = st2 / dq2 * wg2;
    intot3 = st3 / dq3 * wg3;
    intot4 = st4 / dq4 * wg4;



    //SUM OF ALL DATA
    tot = intot1 + intot2 + intot3 + intot4;


    ed5.setText(precision.format(tot));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the precision.format(tot) line. The DecimalFormat object has been initialized with the format ".2" which means that it will format the number to two decimal places. However, in the line ed5.setText(precision.format(tot));, the formatted number is being assigned to a TextView which may have a different format or may be rounding off the number to zero decimal places.

To fix this, you can try using the String.format method to format the number to two decimal places and then set it to the TextView as a string.

Here's the updated code:

public void avgcal() {
double avg = .0, tot, wg1, wg2, wg3, wg4, dq1, dq2, dq3, dq4, st1, st2, st3, st4, intot1, intot2, intot3, intot4;

```
// Subject grades calculator
wg1 = Double.parseDouble(ed2.getText().toString());
dq1 = Double.parseDouble(ed3.getText().toString());
st1 = Double.parseDouble(ed4.getText().toString());

wg2 = Double.parseDouble(ed8.getText().toString());
dq2 = Double.parseDouble(ed9.getText().toString());
st2 = Double.parseDouble(ed10.getText().toString());

wg3 = Double.parseDouble(ed11.getText().toString());
dq3 = Double.parseDouble(ed12.getText().toString());
st3 = Double.parseDouble(ed13.getText().toString());

wg4 = Double.parseDouble(ed19.getText().toString());
dq4 = Double.parseDouble(ed20.getText().toString());
st4 = Double.parseDouble(ed21.getText().toString());

intot1 = st1 / dq1 * wg1;
intot2 = st2 / dq2 * wg2;
intot3 = st3 / dq3 * wg3;
intot4 = st4 / dq4 * wg4;

// SUM OF ALL DATA
tot = intot1 + intot2 + intot3 + intot4;

// Format the number to two decimal places and set it to the TextView
ed5.setText(String.format("%.2f", tot));
```

}

This code should format the number to two decimal places and set it to the TextView.